# Accord du participe passé dans « que j'ai pu côtoyer »

Tags: accord, participe-passé

> J'ai partagé mes connaissances en physique ainsi que ma passion pour la science aux étudiants que j'ai pu côtoyer.

Je me demande s'il faut faire l'accord (pus) ou pas. Je pense non mais il me manque la justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le participe passé du verbe pouvoir est invariable, on emploie toujours la forme **pu**.

Voir [conjugaison](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/pouvoir.html) (en fin de page).
Voir [aussi](http://www.conjugaison-verbe.net/verbe/pouvoir/participe-passe).

Comment: L'explication c'est que le complément de pouvoir n'est pas « les étudiants » mais la proposition infinitve « côtoyer les étudiants », il n'y a donc pas d'accord à faire.